# How to display Apple Watch unable to connect screens?

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-watch, wkinterfacecontroller

I am developing an Apple Watch app and trying to handle the error cases of not being able to connect to the iPhone:

[image: No connection Screen]

And needing to unlock the iPhone to access it:

[image: Unlock iPhone screen]

I have seen several apps that have these identical screens, so they must be a part of the system. However I am unable to display these in my app. Is there something I need to set for them to appear? I am also wondering if these screens were removed in watchOS 2.0.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no default screen for showing such information, you have to handle connection issues by yourself.